# possible bug with Limit

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs, version-11.3

Evaluate this limit analytically

```
Limit[Sum[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/n, {i, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

Mathematica 11.3 gives `0`.

But using numerical calculations

```
Needs["NumericalCalculus`"];
NLimit[Sum[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/n, {i, n}], n -> Infinity]
```

gives `1.1477936343307347`.

Comment: What is the value of i?

Comment: Yes, possible a bug. It should be returns  unevaluated.

Comment: Maple 2018.1 outputs $ 1/2\,\sqrt {2}+1/2\,\ln  \left( 1+\sqrt {2} \right) .$ This is a certain definite integral as  the limit of its integral sums.

Comment: For an approximation: `Limit[Sum[
   Series[Sqrt[1 + i^2/n^2]/n, {n, Infinity, 125}] // Normal, {i, n}],
   n -> Infinity] // N`

Comment: Now returns unevaluated in 13.3.0.

Answer (score 3):

This is not the answer to your question, but how to find symbolic solution to the limit.

---

Using identity:

$$\sum _{k=0}^{\infty } -\frac{\Gamma \left(k-\frac{1}{2}\right) (1-x)^k}{\left(2 \sqrt{\pi }\right) k!}=\sqrt{x}$$

So:

```
func = -1/(2 Sqrt[Pi])*Gamma[k - 1/2]/(k! n)*(1 - x)^k /. 
x -> (1 + i^2/n^2) // PowerExpand

Sum[Limit[Sum[func, {i, n}], n -> Infinity, Assumptions -> k >= 0], {k, 0, Infinity}]

(* 1/2 (Sqrt[2] + ArcSinh[1]) *)

N[%,20]
(* 1.1477935746963190370 *)
```

Comment: Nice idea.Is it possible to evaluate `Limit[Sum[Sqrt[(1 - 4*i + 4*i^2 - 4*n + 8*i*n + 5*n^2)/n^4], {i, n}], n -> ∞]` in this way? The symbolic solution should be `1/4 (-2 Sqrt[5]+4 Sqrt[17]-ArcSinh[2]+ArcSinh[4])`.

Comment: @mathe .And what has to do with the first question?Then check and see what happens.